# When updating the state of the search input it is always 1 input behind in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm grabbing the input from my search bar and updating the state using the event.target.value but it always has a 1 character input delay.

So for example if I type "Pizza" it will show "Pizz" -- always one letter short so the search functionality works but it needs multiple inputs because it wont update the state until after 2 inputs are there

Feel like I must be overlooking something simple but can't seem to see it

```
function App() {

  const [ search, setSearch ] = useState('');
  const [filteredRecipes, setFilteredRecipes] = useState(items);

  const handleSearchChange = (event) => {
    setSearch(event.target.value);
    setFilteredRecipes(items.filter(item => {
      return (
        item.Name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
      )
    }))
    console.log(search);
  }

/* Elsewhere in code --> updating state using "onChange" */

<InputBase 
    className={classes.SearchField}
    placeholder='Search...' 
    onChange={handleSearchChange}
/>
```

Comment: Let me start by saying I don't use react, but `change` usually happens after `blur`, so use `oninput`, if that's the issue. When I have come across something like your issue it had to do with  `onkeydown` when it should have been `onkeyup`, since the key was not registered until `keyup`.

Answer (score 3):

The function `handleSearchChange` should be responsible for only handling the change of the search `input`. You should be filtering the items inside a `useEffect` hook, which will filter the input when the search value changes.

Because state changes are asynchronous when you call `setFilteredRecipes` inside the `handleSearchChange` it is not guaranteed that the `setFilteredRecipes` will use the latest value of search. Hence calling `setFilteredRecipes` inside `useEffect` is the best choice here.

Example

```
const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const [filteredRecipes, setFilteredRecipes] = useState(items);

  const handleSearchChange = event => {
    setSearch(event.target.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setFilteredRecipes(
      items.filter(el => el.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()))
    );
  }, [search, items]);


  // you must pass search as value and handleSearchChage as onChange handler to your input element
  <input type="search" value={search} onChange={handleSearchChange}/>
```

Take a look at the demo in codesandbox [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-quzwg?file=/App.js:207-543)